# Windows Phone Emulator Not Show The Alert using in phone gap

Tags: jquery, html, windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm developing a wp7 application using phone gap version 2.9.0 
Before I just working in version 2.0.0 alert are working but now i using 2.9.0 the same alert not working now .
below i add my code used.

```
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="return confirm('are you sure')"; />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery v1.10.2 .js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hi");
    });
    </script>
```

both the onclick return and alert not show in emulator but the same code work fine in all browser including IE9,8,7.
can anyone plz provide me a detailed solution for my problem.
following things i all ready try.

Try1

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
// IE does NOT provide an alert method, you can patch it with this line after deviceready.
window.alert = window.alert || navigator.notification.alert;

alert("Hello World WP7");


}
```

Try2 [add this code in config.xml file]

```
<feature name="Notification">
      <param name="wp-package" value="Notification"/>
  </feature>
```

Nothing Help Any other method Available or I just change any thing in above code.

Answer (score 4):

I Solve My Problem

FirstAdd the following Code in Config file

```
<feature name="Notification">
<param name="wp-package" value="Notification"/>
</feature>
```

Then In Html File Or Any Other File Just Add The Following Code For Alert

```
navigator.notification.alert("xxxxxx");
```

Now Its Worked

Comment: Sorry @Gurunathan this did not work for me on WP7 with cordova 3.3.1 :-(  With WP8 all alerts work without any problems.

Comment: yes @user4500 In WP8 alert work without add this code. but the same code Work For Me in WP7. Plz Send Me the Sample Code You try...